# Compact Framework 3.5 App Loses Font Styles

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, compact-framework

I have a basic Compact Framework v3.5 application running on Zebra MC2180 mobile barcode scanners and have a very intermittent issue.

Occasionally (after approx 1 in 20 or so scans), all font styles set on all labels, buttons, etc are lost and revert to the default size 9 font.  Any specific "bold" settings or font sizes are lost.

No exceptions are thrown, there is no indication anything has gone wrong except the missing font styles....

If I write a trace on the font style property, when the font info is lost, I get a System.Drawing exception but no further information. It seems to me it is trying to access an unset property? Eg:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(btn_orderChecking.Font.Style);
```

Produces (very intermittently):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Symbol.Barcode2.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The program '[0x2C50F9A] MC2180.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The method producing the error is below. This code snippet takes a barcode and displays product info (pulled from a web service)

case PANEL_PLU:

```
                        clearPLUpanel();
                        pluDataPartno.Text = "LOADING"; // This never gets seen - panel doesn't get repainted
                        lblScanBarcode.Hide();
                        panelError.Hide();

                        payload = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                        payload.Add("barcode", scanData.Text);
                        request = new dataRequest("plu",payload);
                        res = dataTransfer.sendRequest(request);

                        if (res.result == "ok")
                        {
                            // We're good, populate and show fields
                            playHappyBeep();
                            pluItem_Id = res.item_id;
                            pluDataPartno.Text = res.item_partno;
                            pluDataName.Text = res.item_name;
                            pluDataFreeStock.Text = res.item_freeStock.ToString();
                            pluDatalAllocated.Text = res.allocated_stock.ToString();
                            pluDataLoc.Text = res.loc_name;
                            pluDataShelfStock.Text = res.item_shelfStock.ToString();
                            pluLabelAllocated.Show();
                            pluLabelFreeStock.Show();
                            pluLabelLoc.Show();
                            pluLabelShelfStock.Show();
                            pluImage.Show();
                            plu_btnChangeLoc.Show();
                            plu_btnAutoLocate.Show();

                            if (res.image_url.StartsWith("http")) {
                                 pluImage.Url = new System.Uri(res.image_url);
                            }

                            if (res.item_freeStock > 0)
                            {
                                pluDataFreeStock.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pluDataFreeStock.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            playErrorBeep();
                            clearPLUpanel();
                            lblErrorHeadline.Text = res.error_info;
                            panelError.Show();                               
                        }

                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(btn_orderChecking.Font.Style); // This is the line that occasionally throws the exception

                        break;
```

Comment: Add more details: Are you using subclassed labels etc.? For me the exception looks like the code tries to access an obkect that is already disposed. We have seen this when updating the GUI directly from inside a event handler, but without more details???..., who can say

Comment: Thanks, added a larger code snippet.   The problem is, no exception is thrown (unless I try to read the .font property), the font info just disappears and all fonts go to defaults

Comment: And no, no fancy label classes - just plain old standard items.  All fonts on all labels, buttons, text boxes, etc are lost.

Comment: Is the code accessing the GUI elements running isnide the GUI thread? Just ask, as the request may block. If not running inside the GUI thread you may need to use InvokeRequired etc. Even some EventHandlers invoked from BarcodeReaders may not be GUI-friendly.

Comment: There's only one thread in the application.

I believe I've figured out this only happens when panels are hidden and then shown again. When they are shown again, sometimes the font detail is lost.

I've worked around it at present by manually setting the font again before showing the panel.. But it's not ideal.

Comment: I'm trying to port an application working on various other CE/Mobile devices to the MC2180, and I'm experiencing the EXACT same problem. Even labels set on the designer to a certain font/size, when their panel is hidden and set visible again, font size changes. As I said, same code works fine in many other devices.

Did you find a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue here. Other devices from Symbol/Motorola. Did anyone find a fix for this?

Comment: Nope, never found a fix.  Other than periodically re-setting the font styles.

Answer (score 1):

This error does not occur in OS version 82.34.004. You should to update OS to this version. 
Ondřej